# Emacs on WLS Ubuntu in Moba XServer - no italics fonts

Tags: fonts, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mobaxterm

I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS installed in a WSL1 container on my Windows 10 laptop.  I also have MobaXterm Pro v21.5, configured with a WSL session so I can run command lines in a terminal tab.  I also have the MobaXterm X Server enabled so that running a GUI program from the Ubuntu command line opens it in "Multiwindow mode" integrated into the Windows desktop.  And I have run "apt install emacs" to install that editor.

Here's the problem: my emacs configuration modifies font-lock-mode to display comments in italics, but that isn't happening.  Furthermore, M-x list-faces-display shows the "italic" face as underlined, not slanted.

However, if I open a MobaTerm session and "apt-get install emacs", then that version displays italics correctly, so I'm guessing the problem is in the WSL client rather than the Moba X Server.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that X11 Emacs renders fonts on the client rather than the X Server, and the client machine was at fault. Running `apt list '*dejava*'` showed that `fonts-dejavu-core` was installed but `fonts-dejavu-extra` wasn't. Running `apt install fonts-dejavu` to get the meta-package sorted the problem, so now Emacs is showing italics properly and I can get on with my life :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have half an answer.  The emacs running from MobaTerm is basically a Cygwin application, so it uses the W32 libraries to talk directly to the laptop display and doesn't go through the X Server at all.

So that leaves me needing to know how to install fonts in the Moba X Server so that an X11 emacs client can find and use them.  Any ideas?